# Error on Launching the First Node Following the Tutorial

Tags: substrate-node-template, tutorials

I was following the substrate get started tutorial. In the "Trusted Network - Add trusted nodes", I was failed to start the first node step.

(I was using the virtual machine and the os is Kali Linux)

I just copied and ran the below code from the tutorial.

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name MyNode01 \
--password-interactive
```

However, it keeps showing the error line and cannot generate blocks.

[image]

I am sure that I have inserted the keystore as below.
[image]

Also, I tried to skip this error and keep following the tutorial. When I used the second virtual machine (also Kali) to connect this node, it also failed. It also showed the same error line and cannot generate blocks. Besides, the peer value also without showing right.

Comment: you should add another validator

Comment: Oh, it seems that I had misundertood the tutorial XD. I thought the tutorial goal is connecting two nodes on separate computers. Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, where i was running two nodes in same system but, nodes not producing and finalizing the blocks
how did you solve @TonyMa